# How do I know what process is running for a systemd-timers service?

Tags: systemd, process, certbot

I'm trying to determine whether a process is running successfully for a service that's scheduled as a systemd-timers service. I have a service scheduled called `certbot.service`, which I can see using `systemctl list-timers`. Where is the definition for that service, and how can I determine the process that will ultimately be triggered for that service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `systemctl list-timers` you are listing the active `*.timer` units.

Example:

```
stew ~ $ systemctl list-timers
NEXT                         LEFT          LAST                         PASSED       UNIT                         ACTIVATES
Wed 2021-09-08 10:32:20 CEST 46min left    Wed 2021-09-08 09:32:47 CEST 13min ago    anacron.timer                anacron.service
Wed 2021-09-08 10:58:47 CEST 1h 12min left Wed 2021-09-08 04:35:18 CEST 5h 10min ago apt-daily.timer              apt-daily.service
Wed 2021-09-08 13:28:09 CEST 3h 41min left Tue 2021-09-07 13:28:09 CEST 20h ago      systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
Wed 2021-09-08 15:40:34 CEST 5h 54min left Wed 2021-09-08 05:01:01 CEST 4h 45min ago fwupd-refresh.timer          fwupd-refresh.service
Thu 2021-09-09 00:00:00 CEST 14h left      Wed 2021-09-08 00:00:01 CEST 9h ago       atop-rotate.timer            atop-rotate.service
Thu 2021-09-09 00:00:00 CEST 14h left      Wed 2021-09-08 00:00:01 CEST 9h ago       exim4-base.timer             exim4-base.service
Thu 2021-09-09 00:00:00 CEST 14h left      Wed 2021-09-08 00:00:01 CEST 9h ago       logrotate.timer              logrotate.service
Thu 2021-09-09 00:00:00 CEST 14h left      Wed 2021-09-08 00:00:01 CEST 9h ago       man-db.timer                 man-db.service
Thu 2021-09-09 06:20:05 CEST 20h left      Wed 2021-09-08 06:01:22 CEST 3h 44min ago apt-daily-upgrade.timer      apt-daily-upgrade.service
Sun 2021-09-12 03:10:53 CEST 3 days left   Sun 2021-09-05 03:10:52 CEST 3 days ago   e2scrub_all.timer            e2scrub_all.service

10 timers listed.
Pass --all to see loaded but inactive timers, too.
```

You can see that in the `UNIT` column we have timer units (e.g. `anacron.timer`)  This is the actual timer that you are listing.  When that timer triggers, it will activate another unit.  That unit can be specified in the `*.timer` file as `Unit=anacron.service` or defaults to a service with the same name as the timer, but with a `.service` extension.  The `ACTIVATES` column shows you this.

If you want to know where the `*.timer` is set, use `systemctl cat <unit>`:

```
stew ~ $ systemctl cat anacron.timer
# /lib/systemd/system/anacron.timer
[Unit]
Description=Trigger anacron every hour

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 07..23:30
RandomizedDelaySec=5m
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

What's especially useful here is that it tells you the name of the file(s).  If you have any drop-ins, they will be listed.

In your case, you are specifically interested in the process that is triggered by your service.  `systemctl cat <unit>` can help you there too.  If I continue with the `anacron.service` you get:

```
stew ~ $ systemctl cat anacron.service
# /lib/systemd/system/anacron.service
...

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/anacron
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/anacron -d -q $ANACRON_ARGS
...
```

You can see the `ExecStart=` line shows the command that is run to start the service.

If you're interested in the current status, you can also see that with `systemctl status <unit>`:

```
stew ~ $ systemctl status anacron.service
● anacron.service - Run anacron jobs
...
     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2021-09-08 09:32:47 CEST; 23min ago
TriggeredBy: ● anacron.timer
    Process: 480643 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/anacron -d -q $ANACRON_ARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 480643 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
...
```

Her you can see when the service last completed, the `ExecStart=` command used, the PID, and the exit code.

Comment: One of the best answers I've seen - thanks @Stewart ;)